# How to send direct message from Page with Attachment via Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I can manage Page Conversations (read, write) in help with Facebook Graph API. But it seems to be impossible to add any attachments to my direct messages.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/conversation/messages

I see only "message" parameter in documentation. So, is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Did you manage to do this in the end?

Answer (score 2):

As @Niraj Shah mentioned above, the attachment sending feature is undocumented (for the time of this post, GraphAPI v2.12), but exists and works if you will post the `source` field:

PHP:

```
$fb =
    new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'your app id',
        'app_secret' => 'your app secret',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.12',
        'default_access_token' => 'your page token',
    ]);

$response =
    $fb->post(
        "/{$conversationId}/messages",
        [
            'message' => '',
            'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($attachmentFileName),
        ]
    );
```

The `message` field can be empty to send an attachment only.

Comment: Can this still be done today on the 3.X versions of the API? And do the source take a URL or ?? Thanks!

Comment: I confirm this working in the latest 4.0 graph api version.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation points out, the API only supports the `message` parameter. So only text can be sent in a message, and attachments are not supported. However, you can try sending the `source` or `url` parameter in your API call and see if Facebook adds it to the message (it could be a undocumented feature).